# Is it the case/is there a proof that the convergence in distribution for the CLT is monotonic?

Tags: convergence, central-limit-theorem

So for instance, if I compare $\bar{x}_n$ and the comparable normal distribution, and $\bar{x}_m$, $m > n$, and the comparable normal distribution, would I expect the difference in former (e.g. the $L_1$ norm of the difference) to be an upper bound for the latter?  I'm interested in the eventual behaviour but also if there's a useful counterexample to the monotonic case for every $n$.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific.  One valid metric on that space is the indicator metric: the distance between two unequal elements is $1$ while the distance between equal elements is $0.$  I believe convergence is monotonic in this metric--but that's not a terribly informative or useful result.  Please describe the metric *you* are interested in.

Comment: The $L_1$ norm of their difference.  However I would have expected that for most norms that it would be monotonic, even if some are uninformative?

Comment: Please edit your post to indicate that.  And shall we presume you mean *eventually* monotonic rather than monotonic for every $n$?

Comment: Edited post to reflect that I'm interested in the eventual behaviour but also if there's a useful counterexample for every $n$ I am interested.

Comment: Maybe the extra detail needed is this: *which* CLT are you considering? The standard Lindeberg CLT considers IID variables, but the Liapunov triangularization gives some power general results. I think you can pick a sequence of variables that is arbitrarily close to "beating" the convergence of CLT but still converges.